# Querying binary values in Python from SQL server

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm executing this query

```
SELECT CMDB_ID FROM DB1.[dbo].[CDMID]
```

when I do this on SSMS 18 I get this:

[image]

I'm aware these are HEX values, although I'm not an expert on the topic.

I need to excute this exact query on python so I can process that information through a script, this script need as input the HEX values without any manipulation (as you see in the SSMS output).

So, through `pyodbc` library with a regular connection:

```
SQLserver_Connection("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                     "Server=INSTANCE;"
                     "Database=DB1;"
                     "UID=USER;"
                     "PWD=PASS;")
```

I get this:

```
0   b'@\x12\x90\xb2\xbb\x92\xbbe\xa3\xf9:\xe2\x97@...
1   b'@"\xaf\x13\x18\xc9}\xc6\xb0\xd4\x87\xbf\x9e\...
2   b'@G\xc5rLh5\x1c\xb8h\xe0\xf0\xe4t\x08\xbb'
3   b'@\x9f\xe65\xf8tR\xda\x85S\xdcu\xd3\xf6*\xa2'
4   b'@\xa4\xcb^T\x06\xb2\xd0\x91S\x9e\xc0\xa7\xe543'
... ...
122 b'O\xa6\xe1\xd8\tA\xe9E\xa0\xf7\x96\x7f!"\xa3\...
123 b'O\xa9j,\x02\x89pF\xb9\xb4:G]y\xc4\xb6'
124 b'O\xab\xb6gy\xa2\x17\x1b\xadd\xc3\r\xa6\xee50'
125 b'O\xd7ogpWj\xee\xb0\xd8!y\xec\x08\xc7\xfa'
126 b"O\xf0u\x14\xcd\x8cT\x06\x9bm\xea\xddY\x08'\xef"
```

I have three questions:

1. How can this data be intepreted, why am I getting this?
2. Is there a way to manipulate this data back at the original HEX value? and if not...
3. What can I do to receive the original HEX value?

I've looking for a solution but haven't found anything yet, as you can see I'm not an expert on this kind of topics so if you are not able to provide a solution I will, also, really appreciate documents with some background knowledge that I need to get so I can provide a solution by myself.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have hex data types. What you're seeing in SSMS is probably a `varbinary` column, presented with hexadecimal notation. In Python you would treat this as a byte array, aka `bytes`. ref: [Data type mappings between Python and SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/python/python-libraries-and-data-types)

Comment: thanks the document was helpful and I also didn't know that this are varbinary values presented as hex for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is simply due to the fact that SSMS and Python produce different *hexadecimal representations* of *binary* data. Your column is apparently a `binary` or `varbinary` column, and when you query it in SSMS you see its fairly standard hex representation of the binary values, e.g., `0x01476F726400`.

When you retrieve the value using pyodbc you get a `<class 'bytes'>` object which is represented as `b'hex_representation'` with one twist: Instead of simply displaying `b'\x01\x47\x6F\x72\x64\x00'`, Python will render any byte that corresponds to a printable ASCII character as that character, so we get `b'\x01Gord\x00'` instead.

That minor annoyance (IMO) aside, the good news it that you already have the correct bytes in a `<class 'bytes'>` object, ready to pass along to any Python function that expects to receive binary data.

Comment: Thanks! so after understanding this I used `print(codecs.encode(bytesSTR, 'hex_codec'))` and got the expected value, ik this seemed like an unecessary question but I really didn't know what to do next.